# Parsing a StdOut StreamReader to JSON

Tags: c#, json, stream

I am using the `Process` class to shell an interactive app. I am writing an instruction to Standard Input, and the result will be a JSON sent to Standard Output across a number of lines.

I am struggling with `EndOfStream` for the `Process.StandardOutput`.

This code works:

```
using System.Text.Json;

Process proc = new Process();

proc.StartInfo.FileName = "xxx.exe"
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

proc.Start();

//Send a command into Standard Input
// ... Code omitted

//Process response
var stdOut = proc.StandardOutput;
string result = "";
while (stdOut.Peek()>0)
{
    result += stdOut.ReadLine();
}

//Create the JSON
var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(result);
```

But it seems a little inefficient. `JsonDocument.Parse()` will accept a `Stream`, so perhaps naively I expected I could just pass the Standard Output stream into the `Parse` function as:

`var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(stdOut.BaseStream);`

But this just blocks indefinitely. The same happens (and I expected the two are related) when I try:

```
string result=""
while( ! stdOut.EndOfStream)
{
    result+=stdOut.ReadLine();
}
```

From reading around this, it appears that for some StreamReaders, even if nothing is available on the stream, the end-of-stream flag is not set. This is fair enough: more might be coming later. **But is there a way I can pass this stream to the JSON parser without it blocking?**

I was wondering if one route might be to inherit from StreamReader, and override the `EndOfStream` property to use the `Peek()` method instead?

As an aside, the interactive app is quite slow, so I would like my JSON parser to get a head-start by starting to parse the (often large) output while it is being produced. Hence waiting to start parsing until I have all the returned lines would slow things down.

Comment: Use `Process.BeginOutputReadLine` and `WaitForExit`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline?view=net-7.0

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for the steer to `BeginOutputReadLine`. It doesn't necessarily aid my problem (as I want to re-use the Process, and need it to hold state), but it has given me a germ of an idea of an alternative approach.